Correct way to link shared library to setuptools extension [MacOS]
I am looking for the best/correct way to build and link shared libraries to a setuptools extension on macOS...
In my framework, I compile and build shared library  (XXX.dylib) without any difficulty with gfortran.
After that, my purpose is to build a setuptools's Extension based on Cython's code that must be linked to XXX.dylib.
My setuptools extension if declared as followed (in setup.py):
setup(
    name='zz',
    version='0.1.0',
    ....
    packages=['ZZZ'],
    ext_modules=[
        Extension(
            'ZZZ._xxxx',
            sources=['ZZZ/_xxxx.pyx'],
            # include_dirs=[],
            # library_dirs=[],
            # extra_link_args=[],
            libraries=[ 'XXX'] 
        )
    install_requires=[],
    classifiers=[
        ...
    ],
)

My approach is the following:

I compile/build the shared library
I copy the obtained XXXX.dylib file (and headers) in the lib (include) folder of my  conda environment (path/envs/py310/lib and path/envs/py310/include)
I build and install the Python package and the associated extension using pip install .

Afer that when, I import the library in the appropriate environment using import ZZZ._xxxx. I obtain the following error:
ImportError: dlopen(path/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ZZZ/_xxxx.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: XXX.dylib 
I run otool -L on libraries:
** otool -L ....ZZZ/_xxxx.so **:
_xxxx.so:
        XXX.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1336.0.0)

** otool -L path/envs/py310/lib/XXX.dylib **:
XXX.dylib:
        XXX.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/libgfortran.5.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
        /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/libgcc_s.1.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.1.0)
        /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/libquadmath.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1336.0.0)

How can I resolve this issue ? It is probably related with runtime path of libraries but it is not clear for me.
